# Unexpected behavior regarding Model property in an Asp Net web API with controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sqlite

I created a simple ASP.Net API with controllers making using of SQLite as a database context. Here's my model, `Todo.cs`:

```
    public class Todo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the context, `TodoContext.cs`:

```
    public class TodoContext : DbContext // Coordinates Entity Framework functionality for a data model
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Todo> Todos => Set<Todo>();
    }
```

I ran the necessary `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` and `dotnet ef database update` to create and update the database respectively. I have a separate project inside the same solution which makes use of `System.Net.Http` to first delete all existing records and then add new ones using the API endpoints. The POST endpoint on my controller looks like this:

```
        // POST: todoitems
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostTodo(Todo todo)
        {
            _context.Todos.Add(todo);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetTodo", new { id = todo.Id }, todo);
        }
```

The DELETE endpoint of my API looks like this:

```
        // DELETE: todoitems/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteTodo(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Todos.Find(id) is Todo todo)
            {
                _context.Todos.Remove(todo);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
```

The separate project (called `InteractWithTodoAPI` first deletes all the contents of the database by calling `HttpClient.DeleteAsync` on my delete endpoint, then it adds a few entries using code like this:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage postTask = await client.PostAsync(repoLink, content);
```

Where `JsonString` consists of a string like the following:

```
"{\"name\": \"Walk dog\", \"isComplete\": true}"
```

Note that `id` is not included here.

Surprisingly, every time I run `InteractWithTodoAPI` (except for the first time), the added entries do not have `id`'s that increment from 0. Instead they increment starting from the last used `id` of the previous session.

There is no code in my Asp.Net Web App that messes with the `Id` property in `class Todo`. Furthermore, I had a look at the physical database generated by EF core in my bin folder, and I can't see anything in the schema which would cause this behavior.

How does my application know what the last used Id was? Why is it using that instead of starting from 0?

## Edit: Database Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
    "MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAING "PK__EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
    "ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Todos" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Todos" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Name" TEXT NULL,
    "IsComplete" INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name, seq);
```

Comment: Look inside your database. What table was created? I mean if it created a column Id Identity(1,1) Primary KEY, it would make sense that every new entity increments the id. A simple Create TABLE statement which is generated in the db, can show you a lot.

Comment: @LongChalk Please see edit for database schema

Comment: there you have it PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT. That's your answer. That means every INSERT (Add) statement - creates a new id - 1,2,3, ...